# Efficient predicate for palindrome in Minizinc

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

To help me learning Minizinc, I am trying to solve an easy problem. My code finds an answer but I am surprised that it takes about 10 seconds to run for such an easy problem.

The problem is "What is the smallest palindromic integer > 10, so that the sum of its digits is > 10 and palindromic too ?".
And I want the code to do large assumptions only: answer has 8 digits at most.

My code is (the toNum predicate comes from hakank website):

```
predicate toNum(array[int] of var int: a, var int: n,  int: base) =
          let { int: len = length(a) }
          in
          n = sum(i in 1..len) (
            ceil(pow(int2float(base), int2float(len-i))) * a[i]
          )
          /\ forall(i in 1..len) (a[i] >= 0 /\ a[i] < base)
;

predicate toNum10(array[int] of var 0..9: a, var int: n) = toNum(a, n, 10);

predicate palindrome_array(array[int] of var int: t) =
   let { int: l = length(t), var 1..l: d } in (
   forall(j in 1..d-1) (t[j] = 0) /\
   t[d] != 0 /\
   forall(j in d..(l+d-1) div 2) (t[j] = t[l+d-j])
   )
;
predicate palindrome_int(var int: n) =
   let { int: size = ceil(log10(int2float(ub(n))))+1,
         array[1..size] of var 0..9: digits } in (
   toNum10(digits, n) /\
   palindrome_array(digits)
   )
;

var int: n;
array[1..8] of var 0..9: t;
constraint toNum10(t, n);
constraint palindrome_int(n);
constraint n>10;  
var int: s = sum(t);
constraint palindrome_int(s);
constraint s>10;
constraint alldifferent([n, s]);
solve minimize n;
```

The complete version has the following additional constraints:

```
var int: s2 = sum(i in 1..8) (t[i]*t[i]);
constraint palindrome_int(s2);
constraint s2 > 10;

var int: s3 = sum(i in 1..8) (t[i]*t[i]*t[i]);
constraint palindrome_int(s3);
constraint s3 > 10;

constraint alldifferent([n, s, s2, s3]);
```

What's wrong/slow with my code ?

Comment: Would you please add the definition for "m" as well?

Comment: Oops, m represented the length of t. But I have now replaced by a fixed value for the simplicity here.

Comment: It is a much harder problem with the two additional constraints/variables. You can test to move out the temporary arrays that is created in "palindrome_int" and add them to the search strategy. Note: One solver (Opturion CPX) solves this problem in < 1s, but Gecode and the default G12 fd solver etc takes much longer (I haven't waited for them to finish, though). And several other solvers give UNSAT due to integer overflow.

Comment: With your advice, the solving time is now divided by 2 ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace "solve minimize n;" with the following labeling strategy:

```
solve :: int_search(t, first_fail, indomain_min, complete) minimize n;
```

On my machine, it then takes < 0.1s.

Comment: Thanks @hakank, it is really quick now !

I now try the full exercise: the sum of digits squared and the sum of digits cubed must also be palindromes, and all numbers should be different.
It now finishes in a reasonable time (5 minutes), but I hoped it would be faster.

Comment: What  constraint(s) did you add for this?

Comment: I have updated the question with complete code. Of course, I have used the same strategy you wrote.